# Form Validators For Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

Are there any form validation comtrols that I can use for windows phone? 
I need to validate if a listpicker (from silverlight tools) is not empty, and make sure a textbox is populated and has valid data in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[FluentValidation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/releases/view/59101) also now support Windows Phone 7

Answer (score 3):

There aren't any default styles that support validation for Windows Phone 7, but you can implement it yourself fairly easily. These resources might help:

- [Validating input forms in Windows Phone 7](http://mobileworld.appamundi.com/blogs/petevickers/archive/2011/02/20/validating-text-boxes-in-windows-phone-7.aspx)
- [Building WP7 Custom Validation Control](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Building-WP7-Custom-Validation-Control---Architecture-amp-Basic-Prototype)